# Events in .Net and relation with the time "dimension"

Tags: .net, events, delegates

I read in many books that events are functionality reserved to be executed at some point in time, not needed "right-away". I dont understand this, and I think it's wrong. It must have to do with the fact that the usual source of events is an I/O device like the mouse or the keyboard. But an event is not this.

Events are "simply" property-like multicast delegates (property-like notion from excellent skeet's book). And a delegate is a "function pointer", a way to "inject" a method as a parameter, in the end helping us to "reverse" the coupling of two objects, allowing us not to reference the "called" object (thus implementing the observer pattern). At least this is the way I use events.

Is the above wrong? (sorry for any bad written english)

Comment: Where did you read this? In what context?

Comment: @oded First thing that comes in mind, is again from **c# in depth**, where a delegate is "something like a testament or will". You write it before your death, to be "executed" after. (relaxed translation from p.28 of the book). This confused me...

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is the usage of events in ***UI and Interactions***, but second is the more generalized description that could be used everywhere and could thought as ***the publish subscribe pattern*** description.

Comment: not considered an answer, because delegates also "possess" this functionallity (pls see comment above).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answer of Jani, I think that you cannot rely on the point in time when your event handler is executed, because you do not know how many event handlers are attached to a specific event in total. If your event handler is the last in a long row of delegates and the preceeding delegates take a massive amount of time to complete your handler will not receive the event thus fast.

The point of events is simply that you cannot know exactly when your handler is called after the event was raised.

Comment: I didnt mean "time" in the way you put it, but in the way its used in C# in Depth (see comment). After all it all depends on the machinery below.